# Not getting "fit to artwork bounds" and "create outlines for all font type" in Illustrator 10

Tags: illustrator-effects

I am not finding the following in my Illustrator 10:

1. Once your object is ready, you need to specify Artboard to use by using Artboard tool (Shift + O)

a.  Make sure your Reference point is centered then choose "Fit to Artwork Bounds" from presets drop down menu
b.  or by going to Menu item: Objects -> Arboards -> Fit to Artwork bounds

2. Next you will need to create Outlines for all Font type objects - this will ensure that what you see on the screen doesn't change when someone else will open y our EPS file and don't have needed Font.

Comment: Hello Sanjay, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. If you have any questions about GD.SE, have a look at the [help] or feel free to ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

**Illustrator 10** has no artboard tool or artboard commands. You must have **CS4 or newer for *any* artboard features** such as the `Fit to Artwork Bounds` feature.

To create outlines of all type, just **Select All** then choose `Type > Create Outlines` -- make certain text objects aren't locked or hidden first.

Answer (score 1):

"Objects -> Artboards -> Fit to Artwork bounds" Definitely exists in CC2015, I can only assume the tutorial you are working from isnt suited to older versions.

There is no option (that I know of) to turn all text objects to outlines in one. 
You need to right-click on each text object, then select "Create Outlines" in the dropdown menu.